# Are arrow keys the way to scroll through Clang-completions in Vim?

Tags: vim, clang-complete

Having read lots of great advice from here and across the www, I'm happily trying to set up my first Vim environment under Linux (for C++). I've added the C.Vim plugin and also successfully added Clang_complete - which both seem to work.  However, I'm using the arrow keys and  to choose between 'Clang-completions' - this seems to go against the Vim grain (of never touching the arrow keys) - am I doing something wrong?

Just trying to get off on the right track - Thanks

Comment: "am I doing something wrong?" Yes, you take somebody's advice as an absolute law.

Comment: You can use arrow keys, if configured you can use the tab key, or any other key really. Really I'm not against people using the arrow keys, and really nobody should be, it's the decision of the person that's using them. Same thing goes to the mouse, although that's another topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, clang-complete's suggestions are pushed in the default vim completion list, which you can open using `^p` or `^n` and navigate through the same way.

Comment: Thanks very much - you set me on the right track. ^p (presumably - previous) and ^n (next?). @honk and Eduan thanks also, your philosophical comments have been taken on board as well.

Comment: You're welcome. And yep, as usual, if there's a `p`, there's a `n`! I'll add that.